# On the double series $\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}}\frac{m^2+4mn+n^2}{(m^2+mn+n^2)^s}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm having a difficult time calculating the series

$$\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}}\frac{m^2+4mn+n^2}{(m^2+mn+n^2)^s} \quad , \quad s>2$$

I don't even know where to start. Truth be told I don't have that much experience in double sums and they are not my strong asset.

Comment: I'll ask the naive question I usually ask whenever I see a tricky series/integral: where did this come from and why do you think it might have a closed-form?

Comment: [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1280031p6730037).

Comment: A way of arriving at my answer is to look at the six pairs $(\pm1,0)$, $(0,\pm1)$,$\pm(1,-1)$ making the denominator $=1$. The numerators of those terms add up to zero.

Comment: @Integrand Yep, that would AOPS. Kent Merryfield posted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that this is a trick question because the series vanishes for reasons of symmetry.

---

Let $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ be two unit vectors forming a 60 degree angle. It is easy to see (law of cosines) that
$$
||m\vec{u}+n\vec{v}||^2=m^2+mn+n^2.
$$
Let $R$ be the sixty degree rotation, i.e. the linear transformation defined by
$R(\vec{u})=\vec{v}$  and $R(\vec{v})=\vec{v}-\vec{u}$.
So $R$ is an order six transformation, and for all vector $\vec{w}$ we have
$$||R(\vec{w})||^2=||\vec{w}||^2.$$
Consider an orbit of $\langle R\rangle$, that is, fix a pair $(m,n)$, and apply the transformations $R^i, i=0,1,\ldots,5$, to the vector $\vec{w}_0=m\vec{u}+n\vec{v}$. It follows that
the vectors $\vec{w}_i=R^i(\vec{w}_0)$, $i=0,1,\ldots,5$, all have the same length.
In other words, the pairs
$$(m,n), (m+n,-m), (n,-m-n), (-m,-n), (-m-n,m), (-n,m+n)$$
all contribute terms sharing the same denominator.

**But the numerators of such a sextet of terms add up to zero.**

Write
$R(m,n)=m^2+4mn+n^2$. Then the first three vectors contribute
$$
\begin{aligned}
&R(m,n)+R(m+n,-m)+R(n,-m-n)\\
=&m^2+4mn+n^2+(m+n)^2-4m(m+n)+m^2+n^2-4n(m+n)+(m+n)^2\\
=&(1+1-4+1+1)m^2+(4+2-4-4+2)mn+(1+1+1-4+1)n^2\\
=&0.
\end{aligned}
$$
The negatives of those three vectors give the same sum for reasons of parity, and the claim follows.

> Whenever the series converges absolutely, the derangement theorem allows us to sum it one sextet at a time, and the series vanishes.

---

The vectors $\vec{w}$ with roughly equal norm $R^2$ fall on the circle of radius $R$ (give or take $1/2$, rounding to the nearest integer here). Given that the vectors form the hexagonal lattice, there are $\mathcal{O}(R)$ such vectors (scales with the length of the perimeter of that circle). The absolute values of those terms contribute thus sum up to roughly $\mathcal{O}(R^3/R^{2s})$. It is well known that the sum over $R$ converges absolutely, when $s>2$, so we are done.

Comment: The quadratic form $m^2+mn+n^2$ is familiar to me from the context of the ring of Eisensteinian integers $\Bbb{Z}[\omega]$, $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$, forming that hexagonal grid on the complex plane. That's why it felt natural to group the terms into orbits of a group of symmetries. It was a surprise to me that every orbit contributes exacty zero. Only works with that coefficient $4$, I think.

Comment: Very clever to 'see the hexagons' in a square lattice.